# Category of elements

Tags: category-theory

I know two definitions of the *category of elements* of a presheaf $P$ on a category $\mathcal C$:

1. The objects are pairs $(C,p)$, where $C\in\mathcal C$ and $p\in P(C)$. The morphisms from $(C,p)$ to $(C',p')$ are morphisms $u\colon C'\to C$ in $\mathcal C$ such that $(P(u))(p)=p'$.
2. The objects are pairs $(C,p)$, where $C\in\mathcal C$ and $p$ is a natural transformation $\hom(-,C)\to P$. The morphisms from $(C,p)$ to $(C',p')$ are morphisms $u\colon C'\to C$ such that $p\circ y(u)=p'$, where $y(u)\colon\hom(-,C')\to\hom(-,C)$ is the image of $u$ under the Yoneda embedding. Equivalently, a morphism from $(C,p)$ to $(C',p')$ is a natural transformation $U\colon \hom(-,C')\to\hom(-,C)$ such that $p\circ U=p'$.

Are these two definitions equivalent?

Also, in Riehl's [A LEISURELY INTRODUCTION TO SIMPLICIAL SETS](https://math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/ssets.pdf), she writes (discussing the case $C=$ simplicial category $\Delta$):

> A simplicial set $X$ has an associated category of elements $el X$, in this case called
> the category of simplices, obtained by applying the Grothendieck construction to
> the functor $X : ∆^{op} → Set$. Objects of $el X$ are simplices $x ∈ X_n$ for some $n$. A
> morphism $x ∈ X_n \to y ∈ X_m$ is given by a map $f : [n] → [m]$ in $∆$ such that
> $yf = x$.

What does $yf$ mean? One can't compose $y$ and $f$: one is a morphism in $\Delta$, the other is an element of $X_m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two definitions are equivalent. A transformation $\hom(-,C)\to P$ is the same thing as an element of $P(C),$ and it is a Yoneda lemma exercise to ensure that maps in the definitions are also the same thing.

$yf$ is the a shortcut for $Xf(y).$ Arrows in the underlying category "act from the right" on elements of a presheaf (functor $X$ applied to the composition of $f$ and then $g$ sends $y$ to $yfg$), so this is a convenient way to denote images of elements under induced maps.

Comment: Isn't what Riehl talks about the opposite of 1? In the sense that in Riehl, a morphism *from* $x$ *to* $y$ satisfies $yf=x$, while in my 1, a morphism *from* $p$ *to* $p'$ satisfies $up=p'$ (target and source are reversed)?

Comment: @user975309 Yes, because what you offer as a category of elements is the opposite of what if usually meant by it. Where did you the definition from? I have only encountered the order of arrows as in Riehl.

Comment: But then 1 and 2 are not equivalent but opposite to each other? You said they are equivalent in the first sentence.

Comment: @user975309 Why? In both cases $pu = p'.$

Comment: So 1 and 2 are equivalent, and both are not the category of elements but the opposite of the category of elements?

Comment: @user975309 Yes.

Comment: Thanks, Кряжев!

Comment: @user975309 It seems that the terminology is messed up. Your definition is for the term "category of elements" applied to a presheaf, which is the opposite of Riehl's "category of elements of a presheaf". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_elements